# MySQL Combining two queries to get two counts

Tags: mysql, select, count, subquery

My table contains items that each have a category number.  I have a nice query that counts now many items it finds in each category.  It looks like this if I was searching for the word "cheese"

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT category, COUNT(*) AS 'itemcount' 
                     FROM mytable 
                     WHERE title like '%cheese%' 
                     GROUP BY category 
                     order by itemcount")
```

Now I have a list of all category numbers that have "cheese" and a count of how many are in each category.  I also use second query to count the TOTAL number of "cheese" items. Rather than doing a second query, is there a way to add all the itemcounts to get the total...So only one query is needed?

`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a `WITH ROLLUP` to your `GROUP BY` clause, and this will give you an extra row at the end of your table (with a `NULL` value for category) which has the total number of cheese items e.g.

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT category, COUNT(*) AS 'itemcount' 
                     FROM mytable 
                     WHERE title like '%cheese%' 
                     GROUP BY category WITH ROLLUP 
                     ORDER BY itemcount");
```

Example output:

```
category    itemcount
restaurant          5
hotel               2
shop               11
NULL               18
```